# initializing a 2d array in JAVA

Tags: java

If I declare a 2d array, for example:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[5][];
```

I thought that you had to individually declare/initialize each of the 5 int[]?
For example, before I assign a value to numbers[0][1], I would have to say:

```
numbers[0] = new int[4];
```

I wrote a small program and explicitly put a value in numbers[0][1], ran it, and it worked without initializing numbers[0] first.
Am I completely off thinking that the individual arrays have to be initialized first in a 2d array?

Edit: My misunderstanding was in the initialization. The 1st 2 statements are ok, because I declared the length of each int[] in goodArray to be 3, which causes all of them to be initialized. Whereas in the badArray declaration, I only declared how many arrays there were(3), so I get a npe:

```
int [][]goodArray = new int[3][3];
goodArray[0][1] = 2;

int[][] badArray = new int[3][];
badArray[0][0] = 2;
```

Comment: That should not work, it throws an NPE when I try that. Could you post a short but complete program demonstrating this?

Comment: in that way you can do arrays with different sizes, for example `numbers[0] = new int[5]` and `numbers[1] = new int[7]`

Answer (score 0):

With multidimensional arrays in Java, you can specify a position, there is no need to individually define them.

Comment: I see. For some reason I thought that you had to declare the array before you set the value at a particular index. I know you do with a single array.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test the behavior of the 2D arrays using examples like the one below:

```
int[][] numbers1 = new int[][] { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}; /* full initialization */
numbers1 = new int[3][]; /* [3][0] is null by default */
try {
  System.out.println(numbers1[0][0]);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
numbers1[0] = new int[3]; /* all three ints are initialized to zero by default */
System.out.println(numbers1[0][0]);
numbers1[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(numbers1[0][0]);
```

Will produce the following output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

int[][] numbers = new int[5][];

With the previous line you have created 5 int[] one dimensional array. Now you need to say the size for each one dimension array before you use them. Java gives this flexibility ao that you can have variable size one dimensional int [] arrays inside 2D array.