# Difference between different array declarations in java

Tags: java, arrays, graph, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search

I want to find all cycles in graph and using this solution [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs)

algorithm works fine, but I want to pass two dimensional array as argument, but there comes in a problem:

the given graph is declared like

```
    static int[][] graph =
    {
        {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {7, 8}, {2, 3},
        {3, 4}, {6, 4},
        {7, 6}, {8, 7}
    };
```

and it works, but I used

```
int[][] intGraph = new int[500][4];
 .....
intGraph[j][0] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);
intGraph[j][1] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i+1]);
intGraph[j][2] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i+2]);
....
```

both array values I can accsess via `arrayname[x][y]`

but when I'm trying to pass it as an argument in: (all algorithm in link above)

```
    public GraphCycleFinder(int[][] graphs) {
    graph = graphs;

    for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i);             //added to check itterations
        for (int j = 0; j <  graph[i].length; j++)
        {
            //System.out.print(graph[i][j]);
            findNewCycles(new int[] {graph[i][j]});
        }
}
```

I get no result, no errors. When I print out i values (to check how far it iterates), it gives me 0 when it loops through my array (but should be from 0 to 500), but prints from 0 to array length this hard-coded array.

I suppose that there is something with array declarations because I tried

```
  int[][] intGraph;
```

and then put values like

```
  intGraph[j][0] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);
```

but I got java.lang.NullPointerException

Any ideas?

P.s. sorry if too stupid question, I'm new in java.

**UPDATE**

Problem is not with array declaration. I commented out `findNewCycles(new int[] {graph[i][j]});` and bouth cycles gave necessary result. Probably method `findNewCycles` in this algorithm can't handle this big array. :( although only 200 vertex and 500 edges. Not much.

Comment: Sounds like either `edge` itself or `edge[i]` are `null`, but we can't tell without a stack trace.

Comment: Did you initialize `intGraph[j]`? Arrays in Java are objects, so `int[][]` is an array of objects, each of which is itself an array of integer primitives.

Comment: This intGraph array is full with values so I suppose edge or edge[i] is not null.
And I'll try to figure out how to get stack trace :D

Comment: You are getting `NPE` from which line?

Comment: Have can I initialize intGraph[j]? int[][] intGraph = new int[500][4]; - int's not initialization?

Comment: tintinmj - I got it when trying int[][] intGraph; insted of int[][] intGraph = new int[500][4];

Comment: No it's not possible. No one can get `NPE` on declaration. Please check the line, where you are getting `NPE`.

Comment: NPE points to `intGraph[j][0] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);`. But only when above is `int[][] intGraph;` not getting if  `int[][] intGraph = new int[500][4];` It must be connected with _shoover_ comment about initialization.

Comment: When you declare `intGraph` as `int[][] intGraph;`, in what lines of code are you initializing it? There is some discussion of initializing 2D arrays in [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263691/initializing-a-2d-array-in-java).

Comment: That is, not only does the 2D array `intGraph` need to be initialized, but also each of the 1D arrays `intGraph[j]` need to be initialized too.

Comment: _shoover_ - thanks for tips, I'll read more about 2D initialization!

Comment: As far as I understood I have to set array dimensions and 2D initialization is done, like here `intGraph = new int[500][4];`. And there is no errors, the only problem that class `GraphCycleFinder` doesn't work as supposed to :D

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points that may help you(I hope they do somehow)

**Array Declarations** as for the title of the question

In java you can declare array in two ways

1. Variable of array datatype(like int array type)

   `int[] a,b;           //both a and b are of integer array type`
2. Array variable of some datatype (like int)

   `int c[],d;           //both c and d are of int type but only c is array`

**Initialization** since it is required
We can declare and initialize array as follows

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      // or
int b[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}};
```

We can initialize the declared array as follows

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2*a[0]; //or any other expression
```

**Things you missed in question or maybe missing in your code/problem**

- `graph` is array of edges and edges have two vertex and hence `intGraph[500][4]` should be `intGraph[500][2]`
- `public GraphCycleFinder(int[][] graphs) {...}` should be `static` if you're calling it in `main()`and at last closing `}` is missing as described above.
- As shoover is saying you must initialize `intGraph[j]` also.

By this we mean in code

```
.....
intGraph[j][0] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);
intGraph[j][1] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i+1]);
intGraph[j][2] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i+2]);
....
```

you are only initializing one dimension within same row or for example if j=1 then you're initializing intGraph[1][0] to intGraph[1][3] only not for all j=0 to 499 except 1.

and most probably **NPE** is encountered because with `int [][]intGraph;` you're not initializing it all elements and trying to copy uninitialized array in function `public GraphCycleFinder(int[][] graphs){graph=graphs;...}` 
and you're not getting it while using `int [][]intGraph=new int[500][4];` because you're initializing all elements and no NULL value is there.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for explaining arrays! It's much clearer now!
But anyways `intGraph[j][0] = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);` i loop throuht and `j` is from 0 to 500 and values is assigned to all elements. and here `intGraph[500][2]` i use 4 insted of 2 because i have to save edge weight value and 4th is 0 or 1 (main task details). And 'public GraphCycleFinder(int[][] graphs) {...}' i'm not calling in main(), it's in other class constructor. :)
And thanks once more for detailed information about arrays!

Comment: you're welcome. And if you can share some more code, then maybe we'll understand where's the problem.

Comment: It's really messy right now, I'll try clean it up, maybe will find the problem. If I don't then I will share clean code :)